# PHP Array Merge in Function

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Im newbie here and i try to ask my question directly!
My problem it's based on array merge in function.

I have this code:

```
GameFiles(array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1", "expirecache" => "0"));
GameFiles(array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1"));


    function GameFiles($params) {
          $default = array('skipcache' => false, 'expirecache' => 86400, 'os' => null);
          $params = array_merge($default, $params);


          var_dump($params);
    }
```

And i get this output:

```
array(5) {
["skipcache"]=>
bool(false)
["expirecache"]=>
string(1) "0"
["os"]=>
NULL
["gid"]=>
string(1) "1"
["sid"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
array(5) {
["skipcache"]=>
bool(false)
["expirecache"]=>
int(86400)
["os"]=>
NULL
["gid"]=>
string(1) "1"
["sid"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
```

The issues is this 2 array in output. I want to merge all array in 1 because if you look on " Key " all is same in 3 array.

If you look on this 2 sender :

```
GameFiles(array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1", "expirecache" => "0"));
GameFiles(array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1"));
```

This will go in GameFile($params) and I set default other array but I want to merge all array in one array !

Thanks

Regards

Comment: `array_merge(array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1", "expirecache" => "0"), array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1"), array('skipcache' => false, 'expirecache' => 86400, 'os' => null));` you don't have to declare extra function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - I can't comment but David Kmenta is correct - you don't really need to have a function. There is one basic problem with your existing code: any time you call GameFiles, you are merging your $default array with the $params array. You're never merging the two arrays you are trying to merge.

To make this clearer, here's what is happening when you unwrap it from your function:

```
$default = array('skipcache' => false, 'expirecache' => 86400, 'os' => null);
$params1 = array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1", "expirecache" => "0");
var_dump(array_merge($default, $params1));

$params2 = array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1");
var_dump(array_merge($default, $params2));
```

You are just printing out two separate arrays. If you have a default array and need to merge it, you just use array_merge() twice like

```
$default = array('skipcache' => false, 'expirecache' => 86400, 'os' => null);
$params1 = array_merge($default, array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1", "expirecache" => "0"));
$result = array_merge($params1, array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1"));
var_dump($result);
```

Or, even possibly more sketchy/useless/overkill if you're lazy and don't want to constantly do re-assignment:

```
$default = function($arrOne, $arrTwo){
    return array_merge($arrOne, $arrTwo);
};
$param1 = array('skipcache' => false, 'expirecache' => 86400, 'os' => null);
$param2 = array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1", "expirecache" => "0");
$param3 = array("gid" => "1", "sid" => "1");

var_dump($default($default($param, $param2), $param3));
```